# What is the range of “reasonable” counts of bisulfite sequencing?

Tags: dna-sequence

I analyzed the bisulfite sequencing data of a mouse sample (1 lane, I think) and it got enormous methylated/unmethylated counts on some chromosomes, e.g. chromosome 2.

I thought it was a very a strong signal, but colleague said it must be sequencing artifacts.

- So where do these sequencing artifacts come from?
- What should be the reasonable sequencing reads for an experienced biologist?
- Are the answers to above questions also applicable to other sequencing methods?

** I'm not a biologist yet, my descriptions may be inaccurate. If so, please point them out. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like more of a biology question than a programming one.